# Save is not Working in django, in shell and Model Form

Tags: python, django

Please help, I have not seen this error before.The save function is not updating my model either in Shell or in the view. It also gives no error message.

```
>>> from course.models import Course
>>> course = Course.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> course.title
'test'
>>> course.title = "NameChange"
>>> course.title
'NameChange'
>>> course.save()
>>>
```

If I exit and then Re-enter the shell

```
>>> from course.models import Course
>>> course = Course.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> course.title
'test'
```

The following will also not work on my update view where I use a model Form, I cant post the code for the model form.

```
@superuser_required
def update(request, course_id):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=course_id)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = CourseForm(data=request.POST, instance=course)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.info(request, _("The course has been updated"))
            return redirect(reverse("course:admin:index"))

    else:
        form = CourseForm(instance=course)

    context = {'form': form,}

    return render(request, 'course/admin/update.html', context)
```

I would post my models.py file but StackOverflow won't let me, says there is too much code.

Comment: do you have a save() method function in your models?

Comment: def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  if not self.slug:
   self.slug = slugify(self.title)
   super(Course,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

Comment: add `super(Course,self).save(*args,**kwargs)` after the if condition so your model can be save

Comment: Wow, thanks! this worked!

Comment: i'll add so you can accep it

Answer (score 1):

As you show, in the model you have the `def save` method, but only save when an if condition perform to solve that you have to call the real save method if it isn't accomplish:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)super(Course,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    super(Course,self).save(*args,**kwargs) # Calling save method
```

[More information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)